# pandas groupby - group names instead of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Groupby.

In my gender parameter.
The values are numeric .

1- male
2- female

Can I change (just for the output!) the values to names?

```
df.groupby('gender')['age'].mean()
```

Out[765]:

gender

1        21.166667

2        17.500000

Name: age, dtype: float64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [series.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) method.

```
df.groupby('gender')['age'].mean().rename(index={1:"male", 2:"female"})
```